# Deleting C:/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/Code/User/workspaceStorage

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, hard-drive

recently my c drive has been very full even tho i wasn't installing programs so i install WinDirStat which helped me alot but i realised that C:/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/Code/User/workspaceStorage folder which i am pretty sure is a vs code folder is taking a lot of space [image]

So is it safe to delete it?

Comment: I had some time problems with a workspace and the database in `User/workspaceStorage` was grown very large, deleting the `.db` files for the workspace fixed the problem of unable to launch an extension debug session. You lose the open files and such

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have deleted the folders inside and vs code works perfectly fine just that the most recent workspace i have used doesn't load automatically

Answer (score 0):

If you've already deleted the folders inside it, there's not much else to say except that VS Code will create the `workspaceStorage` directory again if it doesn't exist. The folder is used to store information for workspaces such as what extensions are enabled, the state of the explorer tree, what editors are open and in what editor groups, extension-specific state/cache info, etc.